# Repairing CentOS 6.5 permissions after file migration

Tags: permissions, rsync, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.5 in a VirtualBox VM. Recently, I ran out of space for my virtual hard disk. To remedy this, I decided to create a second hard disk for the `/usr` directory. I mounted that and copied over files as root with `rsync -a /usr.bak /usr`. This seemed to have preserved all file ownership and permissions.

However, now I'm getting weird permission issues. While I can boot the system just fine, various things don't work, like:

1. The network adapter doesn't work `sudo service network restart` fails while "Determining IP information for eth0."
2. Doing an ACPI shutdown no-longer pops up the same dialog in Gnome.
3. I see some "/usr/bin/logger: Permission denied" errors.

I had disabled SELinux earlier, so I don't think this is interfering. I also tried to fix permissions by running this as root, but the problem persists:

```
for i in `rpm -qa`;do rpm --setperms $i;done
```

What could have been messed up in my copying files using `rsync` to this new mount point? Anything I can do to repair things? Note that this is a development sandbox, so I'm not super concerned if a fix would involve a non-ideal security setup.

Answer (score 1):

rsync works as below.

```
rsync options source destination
```

But what you have done is,

```
rsync -a /usr.bak /usr
```

Shouldn't be the other way around?

As far as I see, you have messed the permissions with assigning the permissions of `/usr.bak` to `/usr`. Change the rsync command after restoring the original permissions in `/usr` directory and then if you reboot the system the issue should be resolved. The restart is just to be sure, though not required.

Sometimes, the permissions might be messed up because of rpm packages too. You can find a discussion related to that issue [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=30784#p143684).

> These files are created by rpm if it tries to update an exiting file
>   which it can't change because of "chattr +i /usr/bin/write". i've done
>   that ages ago after i removed the setuid-flag. strange thing, is that
>   the +i was gone on write and chsh and the setuid was back.

Comment: I renamed the original `/usr` to `/usr.bak`, mounted the new `/usr`, then ran that command. `/usr.bak` *is* the source.

Comment: So `/usr/bin/logger` should be read from `/usr.bak/bin/logger` now, instead?

Comment: No. I copied the files that were previously in `/usr` (`/usr.bak`) to the *new* `/usr` directory.

Comment: @Jacob, I think the issue might be with `rpm` as pointed out in the forum that I had provided. However, I am not sure if there could be some other issues other than this.